# Updating value of tableView with Realtime Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

My Code below performs following action. It connects to a Firebase Realtime Database and looks which newsfeed the user is following right now and puts it in an array. Then the code get written comments from the separate feed and combines it in one feed in a tableView.

My problem is following. When the user starts the view for the first time it loads everything correct. But as soon somethings change it observes if somethings changed and adds the changed comment to the feed. But then I have the same comment two times. The old comment and the new comment.

I need a way to update or remove the old value and show the new value. I am pretty sure I have to use `self.table.removeAll()` but I don't now where. I can not use it like below because this will cause that only the last feed from the array will be shown.

```
    func datenBankAbfrage() {
        
        for name in myFeed.myArray1[0..<myFeed.myArray1.count] {
            ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(name)")
                     
                     ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                         self.table.removeAll()
                         
                     for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                         let Object1 = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                         let userName = Object1?["userName"]
                         let userGroup = Object1?["userGroup"]
                         let userComment = Object1?["userComment"]
                         
                         let video = importComment(
                             userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
                             userComment: userComment as! String)

                         self.table.append(video)
                         self.table = self.table.sorted { $0.userTime! > $1.userTime! }
                         self.tableView.reloadData()
                     }
                 }
            myFeed.myArray1 = []
        }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to have a dictionary/struct for this

```
 var dic = [String:[ImportComment]]()
```

Then in place of

```
self.table.removeAll()
```

Put

```
self.dic[name] = [] // you only delete items for specific name
```

And after the `for video in snapsho....{}` add this

```
self.dic[name] = specificNameVideos // you only set items to specific name
```

Where `specificNameVideos`  is

```
var specificNameVideos = [ImportComment]()
```

That you fill with contents from the mentioned for loop, And any time you need all comments

```
var allComments = Array(dic.values).flatMap { $0 } // You can also sort allComments with userTime property
```

**Edit:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dic = [String:[ImportComment]]()
    var table = [ImportComment]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        datenBankAbfrage()
    }

    func datenBankAbfrage() {
        
        for name in myFeed.myArray1[0..<myFeed.myArray1.count] {
            ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(name)")
                     
                     ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                         self.dic[name] = []
                         
                     var specificNameVideos = [ImportComment]()

                     for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                         let Object1 = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                         let userName = Object1?["userName"]
                         let userGroup = Object1?["userGroup"]
                         let userComment = Object1?["userComment"]
                         
                         let video = importComment(
                             userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
                             userComment: userComment as! String)

                         specificNameVideos.append(video)
                     }
                     self.dic[name] = specificNameVideos
                     let tem = Array(dic.values).flatMap { $0 } // You can also sort allComments with userTime property
                     self.table = tem.sorted { $0.userTime! > $1.userTime! }
                     self.tableView.reloadData()
                 }
            myFeed.myArray1 = []
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. But I struggle to know where to put what. If it is not too much to ask for can you please adapt it to the code above? If I try to do like you said it always says cannot find name in scope.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it now and it shows me a blank table. The content of specificNameVideos is an empty Array.

Comment: I tried it again and again for hours but no table is shown. Did you maybe forget to append the comment to the table? You are reloading the table. But I don't see anywhere where you append anything to the table.

Comment: @submariner i renamed it `allComments` please check last edit

Comment: I tried it and not it shows the table great! But what happens if the user deselects a feed. For example he follows 3 newsfeed and now only 2 newsfeed. The feed are stored in myFeed.myArray. Right now the table does not update the feed. After deselecting it still shows 3 feeds.

Comment: then you should reload everything or you can store feed id with  every item inside `table` array then filter it as you need